# What do these JSX elements with no names mean?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just came across this React code that contains tags with no name (`<>` and `</>`). It breaks syntax highlighting on my editor but I guess it's valid since it's been there for a while. Any idea what it means and what this pattern is?

```
return (
    <>
        <span className="example">{something}</span>
        <br />
        {object.example}{' '}
    </>
);
```

Comment: Those are Fragments. Read about them in documentation  https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Comment: Those are React Fragments. The syntax is a syntactic sugar for `<React.Fragment>` (I personally don't like it). More info: https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<></>` is the same as `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>` so you don't need to wrap your `span` and `br` elements with another element.

Here's the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html#what-are-fragments).

This code (From the documentation):

```
const { Fragment } = React;
<Fragment>
  <ChildA />
  <ChildB />
  <ChildC />
</Fragment>
```

Is the same as:

```
<>
  <ChildA />
  <ChildB />
  <ChildC />
</>
```

**Note:** if you use `<></>` you don't need to declare `React.Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

This is react `Fragment` short pattern.

Here is the docs and exanples: [docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html)